# php 5.2.17 date('T') gives incorrect timezone. Server time+phpinfo time are correct

Tags: timezone, centos, php

I am having a bit of a weird issue:

- the date function gives timezone=MST
- the date function from the centOS prompt gives me EST
- the `phpinfo()` function returns **America/New_York**

As Plesk was showing America/New_York but centOS was not, Techsupport did something to the 
`/usr/share/zoneinfo/` files, because they said that somehow the New_York file was showing MST (Mountain Time).

After that operation, centOS time and `phpinfo()` display EST correctly but the date function still display MST.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your PHP on the command line may be using a different php.ini than your server's.

Comment: Strongly recommend upgrading your PHP -- 5.2 was declared end-of-life nearly two years ago and has been completely unsupported since then. There have been some important security patches in the meanwhile then which have not been backported to 5.2.

Comment: I wish I could. However, it's not certain the problem would be resolved. At this point there is no telling what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried `date_default_timezone_set()`?

> Since PHP 5.1.0 (when the date/time functions were rewritten), every call to a date/time function  will generate a E_NOTICE if the timezone isn't valid, and/or a E_WARNING message if using the system settings or the TZ environment variable.

Comment: This can be set in the php.ini file as well to avoid having to make this function call all the time.

Comment: Fyi: I even set default timezone in the php.ini, just to make sure.  Also doesn't strike you guys as weird that phpinfo returns the correct timezone but date does not?